# Tomcat 7.0.25 is not starting with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, tomcat7

I have configured Tomcat 7.0.25 with eclipse indigo. When I start tomcat from eclipse , I get following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

I also get a logging error, but I added tomcat-juli.jar to classpath. However I am not able to resolve above error. Although I have verified that catalina.jar is present in TOMCAT_HOME/bin folder, it seems it is not picked in classpath when tomcat is started. I am using JDK 1.6.0_29 .

Any inputs ???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a corrupted 7.0.25 install. There is no need to add catalina.jar to the bin directory. The only JARs required in bin are bootstrap.jar, commons-daemon.jar and tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: The external CLASSPATH variable is not used, it's not predicatable.